# space in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, space

I have a little problem. I have a code with a form input, but the form input class is named

`text-input small-input`

I can't change this because of CSS issues and this is the problem, because when I add the space in my javascript code, my code doesn't work anymore

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text-input*small-input').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $(this) .val();
        $.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);

            $('.result li').click(function() {
                var result_value = $(this).text();
                $('.text-input*small-input') .val(result_value);
                $('.result').html(' ');
            });

        });

    });
});
```

So at the * sign, there needs to be a space. Any way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `$('.text-input')....` will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do not want a space, you want nothing there. just `.text-input.small-input` to tell the selector engine to look for an element with both of those classes.

[here](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) is a very good article explaining multiple part selectors.

Comment: No problem. another good place to read is the MDN CSS Selectors page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors it has a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

You had two issues.  You don't want a space and you do want a dot on the second class.

To specify a requirement of two classes on the same object in a CSS selector, you put no space between the two class names:

```
$('.text-input.small-input')    // find single object with both classes on it
```

With a space, it does something different:

```
$('.text-input .small-input')    // find .small-input with ancestor .text-input
```

When you put a space between them, that creates a selector that finds an object that matches `.text-input` and a child that matches `.small-input` and the matched object is the child.  No space between them means both classes must be on the same object.  This is how CSS specifications work and isn't jQuery-specific.

---

FYI, what you were trying to do with this:

```
$('.text-input small-input')  // find <small-input> with ancestor that is .text-input
```

was trying to find an object with a tag of `<small-input>` that had an ancesotr of `.text-input` because you put no special character in front of `small-input` so it was interpreted as a tag name.

Comment: Not me,but probably because '.text-input .small-input' does not mean "find .small-input with parent .text-input" but "find .small-input point with ancestor .text-input"

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and I won't downvote, but it's possible somebody wondered why you felt like adding a new answer after rlemon's one.

Comment: @dystroy - I started writing my answer before there was another one and then I added a lot more explanatory text for the different cases.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wondered if that was the case. Then, I don't think this should be downvoted but I think it explains it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - that is no longer the case in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought your answer was ok to begin with, I personally don't mind similar answers, I just pointed out that it was the sort of minor inaccuracy that might get it downvoted, I'm glad you fixed it.